# Solr Custom Similarity - Using a field from the indexed document

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrcloud

We are currently on a very old version of `Lucene V 4.X` and are now migrating to `Solr V 7.4.0` cloud. We had a custom Similarity Class that we use to influence the score using an indexed field ("RANK") we have in the documents.

Here is how the classes looks like -

**CustomSimilarity.java**

```
public class CustomSimilarity extends Similarity {
    private final Similarity sim;
    private final double coefficiency;
    private String popularityRank;
    static InfoStream infoStream;

    public CustomSimilarity() {
        this.sim = new CustomPayloadSimilarity();
        this.coefficiency = 0.1;
        this.popularityRank = "RANK";
        infoStream = new LoggingInfoStream();
    }

    @Override
    public long computeNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
        return sim.computeNorm(state);

    }

    @Override
    public SimWeight computeWeight(float queryBoost, CollectionStatistics collectionStats, TermStatistics... termStats) {
        final Explanation idf = termStats.length == 1 ? ((PclnPayloadSimilarity) sim).idfExplain(collectionStats, termStats[0]) : ((PclnPayloadSimilarity) sim)
            .idfExplain(collectionStats, termStats);
        float[] normTable = new float[256];
        for (int i = 1; i < 256; ++i) {
            int length = SmallFloat.byte4ToInt((byte) i);
            float norm = ((PclnPayloadSimilarity) sim).lengthNorm(length);
            normTable[i] = norm;
        }
        normTable[0] = 1f / normTable[255];
        return new IDFStats(collectionStats.field(), queryBoost, idf, normTable);
    }

    public float sloppyFreq(int distance) {
        return 1.0f / (distance + 1);
    }

    public float scorePayload(int doc, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public SimScorer simScorer(SimWeight weight, LeafReaderContext context) throws IOException {
        final IDFStats idfstats = (IDFStats) weight;
        final NumericDocValues rank1Value = context.reader().getNumericDocValues(popularityRank);
        infoStream.message("PCLNSimilarity", "NumericDocValues-1 >> rank1Value = " + rank1Value);
        System.out.println("NumericDocValues-1 >> rank1Value = " + rank1Value);

        return new SimScorer() {

            @Override
            public Explanation explain(int doc, Explanation freq) throws IOException {
                return super.explain(doc, freq);
            }

            @Override
            public float score(int doc, float freq) throws IOException {
                // float weightValue = idfstats.queryWeight;
                // // logger.trace("weight " + weightValue + "freq " + freq);
                //
                // float score = 0.0f;
                // if (rank1Value != null) {
                // score = (float) rank1Value.longValue() + score;
                // }
                //
                // if (coefficiency > 0) {
                // score = score + (float) coefficiency * weightValue;
                // }
                // return score;
                return (float) rank1Value.longValue();
            }

            @Override
            public float computeSlopFactor(int distance) {
                return sloppyFreq(distance);
            }

            @Override
            public float computePayloadFactor(int doc, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {
                return scorePayload(doc, start, end, payload);
            }
        };
    }

    static class IDFStats extends SimWeight {
        private final String field;
        /** The idf and its explanation */
        private final Explanation idf;
        private final float boost;
        private final float queryWeight;
        final float[] normTable;

        public IDFStats(String field, float boost, Explanation idf, float[] normTable) {
            // TODO: Validate?
            this.field = field;
            this.idf = idf;
            this.boost = boost;
            this.queryWeight = boost * idf.getValue();
            this.normTable = normTable;
        }
    }

}
```

**CustomPayloadSimilarity.java**

```
public class CustomPayloadSimilarity extends ClassicSimilarity {

    @Override
    public float tf(float freq) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public float scorePayload(int doc, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {
        if (payload != null) {
            return PayloadHelper.decodeFloat(payload.bytes, payload.offset);
        } else {
            return 1.0F;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Explanation idfExplain(CollectionStatistics collectionStats, TermStatistics termStats) {
        final long df = termStats.docFreq();
        final long docCount = collectionStats.docCount() == -1 ? collectionStats.maxDoc() : collectionStats.docCount();
        final float idf = idf(df, docCount);
        return Explanation.match(idf, "idf(docFreq=" + df + ", docCount=" + docCount + ")");
      }

}
```

As you can notice, since we want to retain the parity (sort of) between older and newer TFIDF implementation, we are still using older algorithm and haven't switch to BM25Similarity.

With the above code, I am unable to retrieve the value of RANK field from the document. So essentially, the following line is returning some value which I am unable to log to the solr.log file -
`final NumericDocValues rank1Value = context.reader().getNumericDocValues(popularityRank);`

but `return (float) rank1Value.longValue()` throws the following exception -

```
"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:546)
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getInt(DirectByteBuffer.java:685)
at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferGuard.getInt(ByteBufferGuard.java:128)
at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput$SingleBufferImpl.readInt(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:415)
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DirectReader$DirectPackedReader28.get(DirectReader.java:248)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene70.Lucene70DocValuesProducer$4.longValue(Lucene70DocValuesProducer.java:490)
at com.priceline.rc.solr.similarity.CustomSimilarity$1.score(CustomSimilarity.java:117)
at org.apache.lucene.search.TermScorer.score(TermScorer.java:65)
at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector$SimpleTopScoreDocCollector$1.collect(TopScoreDocCollector.java:64)
at org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:263)
at org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:214)
at org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:39)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:662)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:463)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.buildAndRunCollectorChain(SolrIndexSearcher.java:217)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1622)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1439)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:586)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.doProcessUngroupedSearch(QueryComponent.java:1435)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:375)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:298)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2539)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:709)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n"
```

Any advice?

Comment: @MatsLindh - do you mind taking a look at this question?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get a value from NumericDocValues without setting the current document with `advanceExact()`. Remember that there's a single NumericDocValues for that accounts for every document, you still need to tell it which document you are referring to before requesting a value. In your score function try adding `advanceExact(doc)` before calling `rank1Value.longValue()`.

It should be like this:

```
if(advanceExact(doc))
    return (float) rank1Value.longValue();
else
    return 0; // or whatever value you want as default
```

Comment: you mean call `advanceExact()` on `rank1Value` like `rank1Value.advanceExact(doc)`? But that is giving me a boolean...

Comment: You shoul call both. First `avabnceExact(doc)` and then `rank1Value.longValue()`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I don't see any exceptions now, but rank1Value is supposed to be a field from my document and it's value doesn't match with what I have in the document.

Comment: That's odd. Are you correctly adding the docvalues field using something like `new doc.add(NumericDocValuesField(name, value))`?

Comment: Hmm...I am using `SolrJ` API to add fields to the document, there doesn't seem to be a way to add NumericDocValuesField to it. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not an exper in Solr, but I see you create docvalues by specifying: <field name="manu_exact" type="string" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="true" /> ... Check that the type is similar to Lucene's long. If you store it as a string it will be garbage, I guess.

Comment: Try using "LongPointField" as the field type.